# How to decode Eth raw log data in C#

Tags: c#, ethereum, nethereum

I have a list of raw log data retrieved from Covalent (https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/137/events/topics/). I know what the event this log corresponds to, but how do I decode it into this event?

It looks like "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d00000000000000000000000097922d241bd4e4ef4bb0e13693284H8ea75a6c52"

The event is something like

```
[Event("TokenFound")]
public class TokenFoundEventDTO : IEventDTO
{
    [Parameter("uint256", "tokenId", 1, false )]
    public BigInteger TokenId { get; set; }

    [Parameter("address", "buyer", 2, false )]
    public string? Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

I expected Nethereum to provide something where I can translate that raw log data into an event like this but I cannot find anything like that. Could anyone help guide me to the right thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token id seems to be a uint with 256 bits. That's 32 bytes which make up 64 characters in the hex string. If you trim the starting `0x` and split the remainder in the middle you are left with two 64 character strings.

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d
```

```
00000000000000000000000097922d241bd4e4ef4bb0e13693284H8ea75a6c52
```

The first one (ending with `"2d"`) should be parsed as a `BigInteger` (prepend the `0x` again before that) and the second one seems to be the buyer address (maybe strip the leading zeros).